# Link with two actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I make a link with two actions?
the links will go to my translated versions of the site and at the same time open up a popup window

`<a id="german" href="/lang?=de">German</a>` -> mysite.com/lang?=de and a popup div #german

`<a id="spanish" href="/lang?=es">Spanish</a>` -> mysite.com/lang?=es and a popup div #spanish

`<a id="english" href="/lang?=en">English</a>` -> mysite.com/lang?=en and a popup div #english

`<div id="german">this div will be display when you click on "German" </div>`

`<div id="spanish">this div will be display when you click on "Spanish"</div>`

`<div id="english">this div will be display when you click on "English"</div>`

anyone?

Comment: I think this can be achieved with JavaScript `onclick()` event, though it sounds highly dubious. Why do you need the link to do the 2 actions? Why not make the page load do the other action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript to open a popup and also open the webpage

open the popup

```
<a href="http://yourPopup.com" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://yourPopup.com','1395171904764','width=700, height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1, resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Pop-up Window</a>
```

open up your new page

```
window.open("http://www.YourWebsite.com");
```

Alternatively you could use PHP to make better use of your webpages, holding all of the strings (in different languages) in variables and just populate a single .php webpage. This will save a lot of time.

Let me know if the .js works for you, cheers